# How to store multiple email addresses

Tags: database-design

I need to store a bunch of email addresses each having a label (primary business, secondary business, etc.)

I have 2 approaches:

1. Store them as columns email1, email2, email 3 - which limits the flexibility in having any number of emails. It also limits flexibility to store additional details related to email e.g. the date of activation of the email, etc.
2. Store them as rows - this allows me to have any number of email addresses and also allows me to have specific properties.

I tend to lean towards solution 2 - any opinions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the email types are cast in stone (etc business and personal), you can put them as columns, but name the columns accordingly. That means, no Email1, Email2, Email3 fields, but a PersonalEmail and BusinessEmail field.

If the types and the number of the email addresses is flexible, always use the second option, with the caveat that this will negativelly affect the UI. While it's easy to put two or three text-boxes to display the first and second email, for an unknown number of emails, you'll need to use something like a grid or a list, that might not look ideal.

---

However, in my experience, the usual use case for this type is that most of the users (99%) will have just a single email address/phone number/street address, but you have some outliers that has like 7 emails entered.

If that's the case you can go for a hybrid approach. Use one of the email addresses (*the* email address in most situations) as a primary adress and store it into the original table, and add an additional boolean field to the table that will show if the user has additional email addresses (which will be stored into another table).

That way you can get the best of both worlds, a simple way to see a persons email-address, without using joins, and a flexybility when someone decides to put every email address he ever owned into the app.

Comment: thanks for the excellent post. Yes, this is something I have done in another area of the design and could possible do here as well.

Comment: How do you go about changing the primary email address?  Edit the user table, remove the record from the email table, then add one for the old one? Seems kind of messy with the hybrid approach.

Comment: @cdmckay - *It is messy* to change the primary email. It involves deleting a row, inserting a row, and updating a row. But if it happens once in a blue moon (I don't recall ever changing a primary email), it's worth the mess to avoid a join that will happen all the time.

Comment: Is it really worth that messiness to avoid a simple join? I thought joins were inexpensive on RDBMSes, or at least this kind of join.

Comment: @cdmckay - I don't know. It depends on what the users are doing. Saving a millisecond on a million queries might be better than optimizing a query that takes five minutes once a month.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you exactly know in advance (for all times) how many email addresses a person can have, 2 is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is more compliant with the normalization model, since it allows for scalability in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second option is better.

In my projects, I use Users 1 - n Contacts.

The contacts table store any kind of contact, so the user can have multiple addresses, phone number and e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 will be best option as it will give you additional properties. Also take a note of the number of email addresses  a user can have before hand.

Answer (score 0):

I propose following workaround or solution: you can add 2 text columns in the db, for each entity which you expect to have multiple values or you want to track history of; as below
1. Multiple definition text column
2. History text column

Multiple definition column could be a text column contain the additional email ids in YAML or XML format, that gets displayed on your UI.
History column is for just tracking older email address changed by user along with additional details (like date of removal)